# Basic Facebook API Login not working

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am new to Android Development and Facebook SDK. I am just trying to link Facebook loginButton with my application. When I click on button it ask me for login details and permissions and then it comes back successfully to app. But again at the same moment when I click on that button it ask me to login again.

```
    package com.example.pranavjain.pranavapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

import org.json.JSONObject;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);





    }





   public void onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
        // If using in a fragment

        // Other app specific specialization

        // Callback registration

       CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

       loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
           @Override
           public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
               // App code


               GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                       loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                           @Override
                           public void onCompleted(
                                   JSONObject object1,
                                   GraphResponse response) {
                               // Application code
                               Log.d("tagpranav", object1.toString());
                           }
                       });
               Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
               parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link");
               request.setParameters(parameters);
               request.executeAsync();

           }

           @Override

           public void onCancel() {
               // App code
               Log.v("LoginActivity", "cancel");
           }

           @Override
           public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
               // App code
               Log.v("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
           }
       });





   }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I have already checked that Hash key is right. Nothing gets logged under "tagpranav" or "LoginActivity".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to add following in your `onCreate()` method as first line:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

Consider moving your code in `onCreate()` method of your `MainActivity`. Below I'd mentioned working sample.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

CallbackManager callbackManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton)  findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        loginButton.setReadPermissions(PERMISSIONS_ARRAY);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        // Callback registration
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
                GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse response) {
                                try {
                                    if (user != null) {
                                        Log.e(TAG, "UserID : " + user.getString("id"));

                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }).executeAsync(); 
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // Login canceled

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // Login error
            }
        });
    }
 }
```

In above code `PERMISSIONS_ARRAY` is array having all your permissions.

One thing you are missing is, make `callbackManager` class variable and add following method in your `MainActivity`.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);         
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.i(TAG, "OnActivityResult...:" + resultCode);
}
```

**EDIT-1:**

A class variable is something defined in a class and out side of method, so that all methods of class can access it.
In your code you have defined `callbackManager` inside a method, so you can't access it in `onActivityResult`. I have made relevant changes in my answer.

Comment: "One thing you are missing is, make callbackManager class variable." Can you please explain me this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the results to the callbackManager in onActivityResult like here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/HelloFacebookSample/src/com/facebook/samples/hellofacebook/HelloFacebookSampleActivity.java#L231

Comment: I can't find out the exact place where I need to put the onActivityResult. Please help.

Comment: You override it in the activity or fragment that has the login button.